# Can't drawLine in TextView's onDraw

Tags: android, textview

I can't draw anything in my custom TextView class.

Sorry thats not strictly true, it works in Eclair but not in honeycomb!!!

The `onDraw()` method is definitely being called but nothing is getting drawn (in honeycomb).

Here is my onDraw method.

```
super.onDraw(canvas):
this.bluePaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.actionBlue));
float pix = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 6, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
this.bluePaint.setStrokeWidth(pix);
canvas.drawLine(0,0,this.getWidth(),20,this.bluePaint);
```

Is onDraw handled differently in Eclair to Honeycomb? Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Honeycomb added GPU acceleration for the UI elements, so there's definitely something different on how it's handled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't manage to solve this problem.

What I did in the end was create my own custom text view using an object that extends `View` and manually drawing the text on there.

I'm not sure why `TextView` doesn't allow line drawing but hey, just another solution to a never ending stream of problems.